# How to detect individual phonetic alphabet like ʌ,ɪ,ʊ,ɒ,ə on Android speech recognition?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine, voice-recognition

Recently, I started to learn voice recognition on Unity. Had tried voice command on both Windows 10 and Android, it works perfectly. But now I am trying to do a project where it uses voice command like "Ah", "Ee", "Oo" instead of "Move forward", " Turn Left"... 
For Windows 10, it have a roughly 60% success rate where it recognize what I had said and do the correct pattern.
While for Android, it doesn't seem so bright as is failed all the time when I tried to give voice command(Had tested out it can only detect words not phonetic alphabet)

For Android currently, I built my project based on a github project
https://github.com/gsssrao/UnityAndroidSpeechRecognition
While for Windows 10, I am using Keyword Recognizer

For both the logic is:

1. Player call out a certain words
2. Then it will pass to a game object which hold script that check whether user input is same as the keyword that I had set in my project
3. If it got a same match, then it will perform a corresponding action else do nothing.

For Windows 10, I am fine with its results as it works most of the time.
but for Android it doesn't recognize any "sound" (Ah, Ee, Ou, Oh, Er... etc) is there a better way to do it or I had misuse a certain function?

Comment: To clarify: By "one phonetic alphabet", do you mean a single letter? So "Ah" and "Eh" should be interpreted as the letters "A" and "E" by your app?

Comment: No, what I meant for phonetic alphabet is ʌ,ɪ,ʊ,ɒ,ə and it sound something like Ah, Ee, Ou , Oh, Er respectively

Comment: OK, I see. You might want to include that in your question, to make it more clear. Also, can you provide any more details about how exactly you are doing this, and what a good answer to your question would look like? It's not entirely clear exactly what you are asking.

Comment: Ok, sorry my bad kinda new to this forum and I also kinda bad on programming. Mostly just doing it for fun. Btw I had edited my question hopefully can help u to understand more about my question